# In Chrome, <select> element doesn't have background color when disabled

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Chrome has default background colors set for disabled inputs, but not for the `<select>` element when it is disabled.  What is the reason for that?  It seems like a bug to me.

Open the jsFiddle link in IE, Firefox and Chrome and notice the difference.  In IE and Firefox the `<input>` and `<select>` both have the same styling.  But in Chrome, the elements have different styling.  I would expect the `<select>` element to have the same background color as the `<input>`.

**See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVsQC/)**

```
<input disabled value="text" />
<select disabled>
    <option>option</option>
</select>
```

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

Comment: You could ask here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/discussion-groups

Answer (score 5):

Because that's how the browser's default styles look.

It is doing it correctly as per those.

If you'd like to fix it to match, you can do so with CSS:

```
select:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228);
    color: rgb(84,84,84);
}
```

Comment: +1 to this, but I think you should also add input:disabled for your sample code to him

Answer (score 3):

Browsers do that for a lot of reason, it may be a result of after the **browsers' authors** UX researches and it may even for the sake of **accessibility reason** or some **visual cue** so that you can immediately see which are disabled.

But if you still want to apply your own style. You could do it like these:

http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/PmhJc/1/

```
select:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228) !important;
    color: rgb(84,84,84);
}
input:disabled {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228) !important;
    color: rgb(84,84,84);
}
```

Note that sometimes, you'll also need to change the "mouse pointers" to a proper cursor or i-beam.

Answer (score 0):

You should not care much about browser default styles, in case you are not a browser developer.
If you want to make it same color, than add styles for Chrome:

```
select:disabled {
    background-color: #ebebe4;
}
```